# Proof that the set of infinitesimal does not consist only of the zero element in Synthetic Differential Geometry

Tags: synthetic-differential-geometry

Thanks to Z. A. K. answer I edited my question

In this lecture [Synthetic Differential Geometry](https://www.math.ru.nl/%7Elandsman/scriptieTim.pdf) they have the following

**Definition 4.3**. An infinitesimal on $R$ is any nilsquare element of $R$, i.e. $x^{2}=0 .$ We denote the collection of infinitesimals on $R$ by $\Delta:=\left\{x \in R \mid x^{2}=0\right\}$.

**Axiom 4.1.** (Kock-Lawvere) For any mapping $g: \Delta \longrightarrow R$ there exists a unique $b$ in $R$ such that for all $\varepsilon$ in $\Delta$ we have $g(\varepsilon)=g(0)+b \varepsilon$.

**Theorem 4.2.** $
 \Delta \neq\{0\} \text {. }
$

the proof of the theorem goes like this :

$g(\varepsilon)=g(0)+\varepsilon b$ for $b=0$, since $g(\varepsilon)=g(0)=0=0+\varepsilon 0$, but also for $b=1$, since $g(\varepsilon)=g(0)+\varepsilon=\varepsilon$. So this $b$ is not unique (because $0 \neq 1$ ), which contradicts the Kock-Lawvere axiom. So $\Delta$ cannot coincide with $\{0\}$.

Why is that  if $\Delta \neq\{0\}$ would solve the contradiction in the proof?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me restate the axiom for you.

> Kock-Lawvere axiom: for any map $g: \Delta \rightarrow R$, we can find **precisely one** element $b_g \in R$ that satisfies the following:
>
> - for every $\varepsilon \in \Delta$, the equality $g(\varepsilon) = g(0) + b_g\varepsilon$ holds.

What happens if we assume $\Delta = \{0\}$? Well, under that assumption we would know that

1. Every $\varepsilon \in \Delta$ satisfies $\varepsilon = 0$.
2. Accordingly, for any map $g: \Delta \rightarrow R$ and any $\varepsilon \in \Delta$, we have $g(\varepsilon) = g(0)$.

But this would mean that for any map $g: \Delta \rightarrow R$ we can in fact find **two different** numbers, $b_g=0$ and $b_g=1$, so that for every for every $\varepsilon \in \Delta$, the equality $g(\varepsilon) = g(0) + b_g\varepsilon$ holds. If $b_g=0$ then we have equalities $g(\varepsilon) = g(0) + 0 \varepsilon = g(0)$, if $b_g=1$, we would also have $g(\varepsilon) = g(0) + 1 \varepsilon = g(0) + 1 \times 0 = g(0)$. This contradicts the Kock-Lawvere axiom, which asserts that we can find exactly one number with this property.

Since assuming $\Delta = \{0\}$ leads to a contradiction, our assumption must have been wrong, and so we can conclude $\Delta \neq \{0\}$.

*edit:* Note that if we do not assume $\Delta = \{0\}$, then neither of 1,2 above hold, and we cannot get a contradiction. Since it is not the case that $\Delta$ consists of only one element, it's perfectly fine and non-contradictory that $g(d) = g(0) + 0d$ and $g(d) = g(0) + 1d$ both work for some specific element $d \in \Delta$, as long as they don't both work for *all* elements $\varepsilon \in \Delta$, the K-L axiom is not violated.

Comment: Thanks to your answer I edited my question

Comment: @amiltonmoreira See the edit on how $\Delta \neq \{0\}$ avoids the same conclusion.

Comment: what you mean is this assuming $\Delta=\{0 \}$, than  $b=0$ and $b=1$ would satisfy $g(0)=g(0)+0\dot b$. than since $\Delta$ consist of only the element $0$ that we would have two elements $b$ for such that for all $\epsilon \in \Delta g(\epsilon)=g(0) +b\epsilon$ . In the case $\Delta \neq \{0\}$ we have only the element $b=1$. Is this what you mean?

Comment: No. For each function $g$, we only ever have one value $b_g$ such that for all $\varepsilon \in \Delta$, $g(\varepsilon) = g(0) + b_g \varepsilon$. The one value that works depends on the function $g$ - the value that works may be $0$ (e.g. for $g(x) = x^2$), may be $1$ (e.g. for $g(x) = x$), may be $\pi$, may be $e^e - 2$, or any other value, really. But if $\Delta= \{0\}$ was true, then multiple values would work for one function $g$ and all $\varepsilon \in \Delta$. Since according to K-L, only one value ever works for a fixed $g$, $\Delta= \{0\}$ is not true, and so $\Delta \neq \{0\}$.

Comment: A. K   what I meant in my comment is this suppose $\Delta= \{0\}$ than $b=1,b=2,b=0...$ would satisfy $g(\epsilon)=g(0)+\epsilon \dot b$ because $\epsilon=0$ so for all $\epsilon in \Delta$ we have more than on $b$ such that for all $\epsilon \in \Delta , g(\epsilon)=g(0)+\epsilon \dot b$ because $\Delta$ consist only of the elemennt $\{0\}$

Comment: That's right, @amiltonmoreira. That's the essence of this proof.

Comment: But for example suppose $\Delta=\{0,c\}$ in this case the only $b$ that would work is $b=1$ because for example for $b=0$ would work for $\epsilon=0$ but not for $\epsilon=c$ so we would have only the value $b=1$  that would satisfy $g(\epsilon)=g(0)+b \dot  \epsilon$ for all $\epsilon \Delta$

Comment: @Z.A.K.  If we prove that "every $\varepsilon \in \Delta$ satisfies $\varepsilon=0$"  leads  us to contradiction then  why can't we conclude that there is only one $\varepsilon \in \Delta$ satisfies $\varepsilon=0$? Thanks.

Comment: @Mike_bb: I'm not sure I understand your question. _There is_ exactly one $\varepsilon \in \Delta$ that satisfies $\varepsilon = 0$, but as far as I can tell that fact has nothing to do with this proof and this question. And in general you certainly can't conclude "there is exactly one $x \in S$ that has property $P$" from "it is not the case that all $x \in S$ have property $P$", why could you? And $\Delta \neq \{0\}$ in particular is a theorem of SDG, with the proof given above.

Comment: @Z.A.K. big thanks! Your explanations and answers are very useful!